# Install uroot in R: available in source form

Tags: r, time-series

I need to install `uroot` package and I obtain the following error:

```
> install.packages("uroot")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Francisco Chaux/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘uroot’
  These will not be installed
```

How can I install? I need some configuration or a direct instalation with rar archive?

I will be gratefull with your help.

Comment: try `install.packages("uroot", type="source")`.

Comment: and do not worry about `Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Francisco Chaux/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’` it is just telling you where it is saving your libraries because you do not tell it where to explicitely